# Attn: J.Q. Public: Your "list index" is "out of range"

Tags: crash, openoffice

I have been using OpenOffice (presently 4.0) to expand and maintain the collection of my favorites that I have written, which is presently 600-700 pages in length and has been modified over time by the addition of (short) works. My experience is that OpenOffice.org does great for drafting a letter or a five page work, but if you want something hundreds of pages long, it becomes remarkably brittle.

I went to do some maintenance, shuffling chapters slightly and providing an added work, when I was unpleasantly surprised by a popup saying, **"List index out of range."** I'm a programmer and a usability advocate at heart, and I winced when I saw those words presented to the general public. That I am also a programmer and know what "List index out of range" means is besides the point; it offers no particular insight as to what the defect is or how I could avoid it. (When I clicked OK, OpenOffice.org crashed completely.)

But I noticed that one part had signs of a variant style of markup, so I tried a potential workaround. Same behavior, same inappropriate error message.

So I have a couple of questions:

First, given this text which I have as HTML and as OpenOffice.org, what options will work? Should I be trying Word, or TeX?

Second, how can I write up effectively that "List index out of range" is unhelpful and uninformative even to programmers, let alone being a worthy offering to the general public?

Comment: Is it really necessary to advertise your book? Your question would stand without that link.

Comment: Though I'm sympathetic to the sentiments, I'm not sure the question stands if we trim it down to the last two paragraphs- the first one seems to be looking for an alternative product, the the second one would probably be better off on SO.

Comment: I've deleted the advertisement.

Comment: @bertieb Any advised URL to report "Hall of Shame" error messages to OOo?

Comment: @JonathanHayward http://openoffice.apache.org/get-involved.html

Comment: OpenOffice has lost a number of its volunteer developers, with the result that bugfixes and updates are moving forward only at a crawl and bug reports are unlikely to be worked on in anything like a timely fashion.  The LibreOffice branch is being more actively developed; you could try LibreOffice and see if it works better for you.  As an alternative in your current setup, could you save each work as its own file, and have a Calc file with a list of titles, each title a hyperlink to the relevant Writer file?

Comment: Things are working now after an upgrade. I got "polite" in the sense of "diplomatic response to something odd or inappropriate" response after someone said "I tried on 1.1.4 on Windows 7 and could not duplicate", closing the issue, and I reopened it and said not to say that you tried another version on another platform and close the issue when you do not reduplicate it there.